# Convert search from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, full-text-search

i need to convert this one from SQL Server into MySQL

```
IF IsNull(@SearchText, '') <> '' BEGIN
SET @SearchText = '%' + @SearchText + '%'

SELECT NewsID,DeptID,DeptName,Title,Details ,NewsDate,img 
FROM @tbSearchtextTb
WHERE IsNull(Title,'')+IsNull(Details,'') LIKE @SearchText END
```

this code will search fro my search word in this columns: Title, Details.

i tried to convert this line but i had lots of errors:

these are my unsuccessful attempts

```
IF ISNULL(SearchText,'') <> '' THEN
SELECT CatID,CatTitle,CatDescription,CatTitleAr,CatDescriptionAr,PictureID,Published,DisplayOrder,CreatedOn
FROM tmp
WHERE CatTitle + CatDescription + CatTitleAr + CatDescriptionAr
LIKE  $SearchText;
```

and this one

```
IF $SearchText IS NOT NULL THEN
SELECT CatID,CatTitle,CatDescription,CatTitleAr,CatDescriptionAr,PictureID,Published,DisplayOrder,CreatedOn
FROM tmp
WHERE ISNULL(CatTitle,'') +ISNULL(CatDescription ,'') +ISNULL(CatTitleAr ,'') +ISNULL(CatDescriptionAr,'') LIKE  $SearchText;
```

and many many other ways but i could not find any.

so if you know please let me know, thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server version can also be written:

```
IF @SearchText <> '' -- null is implicitly <> ''
BEGIN

SELECT NewsID,DeptID,DeptName,Title,Details ,NewsDate,img 
FROM @tbSearchtextTb
WHERE IsNull(Title,'')+IsNull(Details,'') LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'

END
```

IsNull is IFNull in MySQL.
Strings are joined using Concat in MySQL
Nulls are implicitly '' in concat

```
IF SearchText <> '' THEN  # << again, this test is sufficient
    SELECT
        CatID,CatTitle,CatDescription,CatTitleAr,CatDescriptionAr,
        PictureID,Published,DisplayOrder,CreatedOn
    FROM tmp
    WHERE Concat(CatTitle, CatDescription, CatTitleAr, CatDescriptionAr)
    LIKE Concat('%',$SearchText,'%');
```

Comment: amazing answer that is really what I was searching for.
thank you so much for you great help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use fulltext search in mysql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html